# Delphi TButtonEdit buttons appear in one project but disappear in another

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a simple form that I use to list the names of all tables in the connected database and allow users to see and edit the data in the tables.  This form includes a TButtonEdit control with left and right buttons to set and remove a filter expression typed in by the user.

I have included this form in two related projects.  It's the same form, using the same source in the same common directory.  In both applications the form works okay except that in one application the buttons are visible and functioning and in the other they are not present.  The don't seem to be created at all (rather than being created with no image) since, when I put the cursor into the Edit part of the TButtonEdit it is up against the left border of the control.

In the same application that has this problem, another TButtonEdit on another form also appears without the button (in this case, only a right hand button is specified).

Does anyone have a clue what might be causing one application to have this problem with TButtonEdit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the button icons, that are "stored" in a `TImageList`, are only included in the *.res file of one of the projects. Make sure that these images are included in both projects.

However, I am unable to reproduce the problem. It works well for me to share a form with a `TButtonedEdit` across two projects.

Comment: I am sufficiently embarrassed that I wish I could delete the question, but then you wouldn't get credit for the quick and correct answer.